# Which artificial intelligence is haram and which is not?

Tags: halal-haram

Today's Artificial intelligence are capable of doing what human can do (playing chess , chatbot) . But to which limit an artificial intelligence is considered haram ? For example , creating a sentience artificial general intelligence which is capable of being a living thing , is it considered haram ? how about artificial intelligence with eye(camera) and ear(microphone) but only can do specific task such as playing chess , chatbot , ect ?

Answer (score 1):

Afaik we have not yet reached the stage where science & technology can create a sentient creature in true sense of the word.

The examples you gave of chess playing or a chatting application are nothing more than a few hundred thousand of lines of either POP or OOPs programming. They do not replicate the human feature of self awareness nor can they take decision that goes against their core SDK.

The same can be extended to an eye (camera) or an ear(mic) both of which are a subset of a larger software designed to perform designated tasks.

We have had robots in the manufacturing industries for almost a century now and yet we are far from creating one that can replace complete human team to research and develop a product independently.

Either you confuse AI with 'creating a life form' or you have misconstrue your question. Nonetheless, I pray you find an answer that suffices your question in the light of Islam.

Comment: okay i get it so ai that only can do specific task is no more than just an algorithm that perform designated task , but how about artificial general intelligence ?  and how to determine whether an artificial intelligence is considered as haram (in the case of it similarities with living thing) ?

Comment: as far as i know , artificial general intelligence (sentience ai) is also "nothing more than a few hundred thousand of lines of either POP or OOP programming"

Comment: @i'mashamedwithwhatiasked I didn't understand your  first comment.